# KOGrid Cell Template $parent is not defined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

A beginner level javascript question...

I need to define a cell template for my KOGrid that is dependent on values in my VM. I want text to be displayed green if an associated field is True else display in red.

I have the following cell templates:

```
var accountEditTemplate = `<div><input type=\"text\" data-bind=\"visible: $parent.selected(), value: $parent.entity[$data.field]" />
                                <span data-bind=\"visible: !$parent.selected(),
                                    text: $parent.entity[$data.field],
                                    css: $parent.entity.accountIsValid() === 'True' ? \'passed-validation\' : \'failed-validation\'">
                                </span>
                            </div>`;

    var costCentreEditTemplate = `<div><input type=\"text\" data-bind=\"visible: $parent.selected(), value: $parent.entity[$data.field]" />
                                <span data-bind=\"visible: !$parent.selected(),
                                    text: $parent.entity[$data.field],
                                    css: $parent.entity.costCentreIsValid() === 'True' ? \'passed-validation\' : \'failed-validation\'">
                                </span>
                            </div>`;
```

These get used in my columnDefs as follows

```
self.columnDefs = [
        { width: 100, field: 'supplierNo', displayName: 'Supplier No', cellTemplate: supplierEditTemplate },
        { width: 150, field: 'invoiceNo', displayName: 'Invoice No' },
        { width: 150, field: 'costCentre', displayName: 'Cost Centre (Dim1)', cellTemplate: costCentreEditTemplate },
        { width: 200, field: 'glAccount', displayName: 'GL Account (Account)', cellTemplate: accountEditTemplate },
        { width: 100, field: 'amount', displayName: 'Amount' },
        { width: 300, field: 'invoiceDesc', displayName: 'Invoice Description' },
        { width: 150, field: 'accountIsValid', displayName: 'Valid Account' },
        { width: 150, field: 'costCentreIsValid', displayName: 'Valid Cost Centre' },
        { width: 150, field: 'supplierIsValid', displayName: 'Valid Supplier' },
    ];
```

This works fine but I want to reduce the code duplication by having a helper function that will return the cell template. Something like:

```
    function GetCellTemplate(fieldName, isValid)
{
    var template = `<div><input type=\"text\" data-bind=\"visible: $parent.selected(), value: $parent.entity[fieldName]" />
                                    <span data-bind=\"visible: !$parent.selected(),
                                        text: $parent.entity[fieldName],
                                        css: isValid === 'True' ? \'passed-validation\' : \'failed-validation\'">
                                    </span>
                                </div>`;

    switch(expression) {
        case 'account':
            return template
            break;
        default:

    }
}
```

This could be called by:

```
var accountEditTemplate = GetCellTemplate('account', $parent.entity.accountIsValid());
```

My problem is when I try this I get ReferenceError:$parent is not defined

What's the best way to solve this copy & paste code growth - I will the same kind of functionality for many fields?

Code updated as per Jason's suggestion - not yet working

```
function GetCellTemplate(fieldName, validationFieldName) {
    var template = `<div><input type=\"text\" data-bind=\"visible: $parent.selected(), value: $parent.entity[{fieldName}]\" />
                    <span data-bind=\"visible: !$parent.selected(),
                        text: $parent.entity[{fieldName}],
                        css: $parent.entity.{validationFieldName} === 'True' ? \'passed-validation\' : \'failed-validation\'\">
                    </span>
                </div>`;
    }

var editBatchVm = function () {
    var self = this;
    var $loadingIndicator = $('#loading-indicator');

    // Properties
    self.recs = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selected = ko.observableArray();

    var accountEditTemplate = GetCellTemplate('account', 'accountIsValid');
    var costCentreEditTemplate = GetCellTemplate('costCentre', 'costCentreIsValid');
    var supplierEditTemplate = GetCellTemplate('supplier', 'supplierIsValid');

    self.columnDefs = [
        { width: 100, field: 'supplierNo', displayName: 'Supplier No', cellTemplate: supplierEditTemplate },
        { width: 150, field: 'invoiceNo', displayName: 'Invoice No' },
        { width: 150, field: 'costCentre', displayName: 'Cost Centre (Dim1)', cellTemplate: costCentreEditTemplate },
        { width: 200, field: 'glAccount', displayName: 'GL Account (Account)', cellTemplate: accountEditTemplate },
        { width: 100, field: 'amount', displayName: 'Amount' },
        { width: 300, field: 'invoiceDesc', displayName: 'Invoice Description' },
        { width: 150, field: 'accountIsValid', displayName: 'Valid Account' },
        { width: 150, field: 'costCentreIsValid', displayName: 'Valid Cost Centre' },
        { width: 150, field: 'supplierIsValid', displayName: 'Valid Supplier' },
    ];
```

Comment: You will have access to `$parent` object inside knockout binding context not inside your JS model. You need to pass the parent model by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken you're just building a string that will later get executed as a template so there's no need to pass in the actual validation object during template construction, you just need the string that represents the validation object. The template itself can reference the $parent context later when it's executed.

```
var accountEditTemplate = GetCellTemplate('account', 'accountIsValid');
```

...

```
function GetCellTemplate(fieldName, validationFieldName) {
    var template = "<div><input type=\"text\" data-bind=\"visible: $parent.selected(), value: $parent.entity[" + fieldName + "]\" />" +
                   "    <span data-bind=\"visible: !$parent.selected()," +
                   "        text: $parent.entity[" + fieldName + "]," +
                   "        css: $parent.entity." + validationFieldName + " === 'True' ? \'passed-validation\' : \'failed-validation\'\">" +
                   "    </span>" +
                   "</div>";
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work for me. No errors, but it seems the values of the params received by GetCellTemplate don't get inserted into the string. I've updated the question with code used

Comment: @RobBowman If you aren't using an ES6 javascript compiler you'll probably need to convert it into a traditional string concatenation like "text: $parent.entity[" + fieldName + "]",

Comment: @RobBowman Is this issue resolved or are you still having trouble getting it to work?